# How to Convert Long into DateTime?

Tags: sql-server

I want to store date time into database table with column type bigint, as given below

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (dt BIGINT);

INSERT INTO @temp (dt)
SELECT (20151201190350100)
UNION
SELECT (2015120290350100)
UNION
SELECT (20151203190350100)
UNION
SELECT (20151204190350100)
UNION
SELECT (20151205190350100)
UNION
SELECT (20151206190350100)

SELECT *
FROM @temp
WHERE dt BETWEEN 2015120290350100
        AND 20151205190350100
```

The date as `2015 12 05 19 03 50 100`
I need to use `WHERE` clause, Is it a good approach if I use to save and reactive datetime, please share if you have any better technique.

Comment: Is there a good reason to use bigint instead of an actual datetime type?

Comment: For reporting purpose i have find that datetime is taking more time than long.

Comment: why a bigint and not one of available [SqlServer types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes) that can store Dates?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is:

Just use a `datetime` data type to store date time values. It will be simpler for many reasons.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp ( dt DATETIME );

INSERT  INTO #temp
        ( dt
        )
        SELECT  ( '20151201 19:03:50:100' )
        UNION
        SELECT  ( '20151202 09:03:50:100' )
        UNION
        SELECT  ( '20151203 19:03:50:100' )
        UNION
        SELECT  ( '20151204 19:03:50:100' )
        UNION
        SELECT  ( '20151205 19:03:50:100' )
        UNION
        SELECT  ( '20151206 19:03:50:100' )

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp
WHERE   dt BETWEEN '20151202 09:03:50:100'
           AND     '20151205 19:03:50:100'

DROP TABLE #temp
```

**Note:** in your sample values you have lost a few 0's at the start of the hour values, where the time is `09:03:50` - your value is `90350`, missing the zero. I have corrected these mistakes in this sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    dt BIGINT,
    val AS CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CAST(dt AS VARCHAR), 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'), 18, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (dt)
VALUES
      (20151201190350100)
    , (20151202090350100)
    , (20151203190350100)
    , (20151204190350100)
    , (20151205190350100)
    , (20151206190350100)

SELECT *
FROM @temp
WHERE val BETWEEN '2015-12-01 19:03:50.100' AND '2015-12-05 19:03:50.100'
```

results -

```
dt                   val
-------------------- -----------------------
20151201190350100    2015-12-01 19:03:50.100
20151202090350100    2015-12-02 09:03:50.100
20151203190350100    2015-12-03 19:03:50.100
20151204190350100    2015-12-04 19:03:50.100
20151205190350100    2015-12-05 19:03:50.100
```

add computed column -

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl
    ADD val AS CAST(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CAST(dt AS VARCHAR), 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'), 18, 0, ':') AS DATETIME) --PERSISTED
```